Nesting two logical expressions in a query of an an array search
Sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bjdy6Z1kp4hwt2n6z1kyERnx01W6mszj_4OxOk4B4vY/edit?usp=sharing
I've designed a schedule builder in one sheet, which searches other sheets for particular codes. Based on the code, that member is populated into a section of the schedule.
I've had no problem with this, but am now trying to expand the search to look for an additional logical expression.
See code below:
=iferror(query(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(INDEX(Pilots!$D$17:$140, , MATCH($B$2, Pilots!$D$1:$1, 0)) = "P1", Pilots!$D$17:$D$140, "")),"select * where Col1 is not null",0))

In this example $B$2 is the date being selected on the Schedule Builder sheet. The formula searches the Pilots sheet for date horizontally and looks down to populate members with the P1 Code in Schedule Builder!C10:D22.
I'd like to add a second logical expression to this formula to look in Pilots!$H$17:$140 to be TRUE (it's a check box) in addition to P1 and populate in Schedule Builder!I31:J37
I have not found a way to get it to work.
Attempted to apply help found here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301?hl=en

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

I'll have to duplicate the sheet and scrub it. It's full of CUI/PII. I'll update

Scrubbed and added sheet with refined explanation.

similar to the current query where pilots with P1 get put into the Pilots section.. I would like to populate members with P1 codes if their "IP" (Column H) checkbox is checked

Manually enter & showcase us the ideal expected output(somewhere in the sheet) you wish to see for this scenario so that we can tally against the formula we create...

I see what you mean. In Schedule Builder!I30:J30 (bordered thick red), the output would show the members I've input (B Flight 2, 9, 12) because on 14 June they're P1 and checked as an IP (instructor pilot) in Column H.


You may try:
=ifna(filter(Pilots!D:D,filter(Pilots!A:SD,Pilots!A1:SD1=B2)=Data!A2,Pilots!H:H),"--")



That works! Thank you. It seems more efficient than the original formula. I've never heard of the filter function in a formula.

Rockinfreakshow, quick follow up. Would it be possible to look for an additional code in addition to Data!A2?  Need to add Data!A42 for that search as well. Keep ending up with a parsing error. It appears nesting is my enemy that I need to brush up on.

Can you showcase the expected output again for this new scenario?!

rockinfreakshow. Expected output has been entered into the linked workbook in the same red bordered portion. The filter would look for Data!A2 as well as Data!A42 with Column H:H being true. Some instructors may be P1 or SLR1 depending on the day. Happy to send over some coffee/beer money for the help if that's allowed!

Any reason on why B Flight 2 & B Flight 9 are excluded even though they are marked P1 and tickmarked in column_H?!

Not excluded necessarily.. just a different day/different tasking. People can bounce between P1 and SLR1 on the same day but may all be instructors. In this instance we're looking at 15 jun. to clarify "P1" is referenced in Data!A2 and SLR1 in Data!A42

the data I mentioned above is hidden since some external filters have been applied for Column A and Column G in Pilots tab; remove those filters & you can see the full data for 15 june

I have removed the filters.

Expected output remains. if H:H is TRUE and someone is P1 (Data!A2) or SLR1 (Data!A42), which should output member 3, 12, 13

https://i.sstatic.net/xVJ9mxBi.png

I see what you mean. my apologies for passing bad data. member 2 and 9 would be include as well.

=ifna(filter(Pilots!D:D,xmatch(filter(Pilots!A:SD,Pilots!A1:SD1=B2),{Data!A2,Data!A42}),Pilots!H:H),"--")
